# Is there a name for "More events than expected" bug?

Tags: bug, anti-patterns

Is there a **name for a family of bugs**, that are caused by assumption, that user would generate only 1 event during the execution of the handler ?

Simplest example is: animation triggered by click, which can run several copies of itself, if user rapidly clicks several times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have described is an excellent example of a...

### [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

A **[race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)** (applicable to both electronics and with programming) is when "the output and/or result of the process is unexpectedly and critically dependent on the sequence or timing of other events."

You have also described an issue with...

### [Reentrancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)

In general, methods that may safely directly or indirectly call themselves are **[re-entrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_%28computing%29)**.  If your event handlers are inadvertently raising other events that you cannot safely handle, you can say that you have non-reentrant code.

In C#, here is an example of code that exhibits a race condition:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1.Enabled)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("We're already ticking, you really should wait!");

    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Okie Dokie");
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Here is a simple example of code that exhibits a problem with reentrancy:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //move to the next cell if we are in the first cell
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 0 &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        //this throws an InvalidOperationException because the Microsoft DataGridView
        //does not handle Re-entrant calls to SetCurrentCellAddressCore
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
    }
}
```

There are a number of ways to solve these types of problems.  Two ways are through [mutual exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) ( such as with [locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28computer_science%29)) or by avoiding the race condition or re-entrancy altogether.

Simple solution to example #1 using mutual exclusion:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (timer1.Enabled)
        return; //just silently ignore, maybe throw up a message box

    timer1.Interval = 5000;
    timer1.Start();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Okie Dokie");
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

*Nitpicker's corner: locking is not necessary in this case because all code is running on the UI thread.*

Here's a solution to example #2 that avoids the issue altogether:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Timer newTimer = new Timer() { Interval = 5000 };
    newTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(newTimer_Tick);
    newTimer.Start();
}

void newTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Okie Dokie");
    ((Timer)sender).Dispose();  //probably not great to dispose in the middle of an eventhandler, but you get the idea...
}
```

Here's a solution to example #3 that avoids the re-entrancy issue:

```
private void dataGridView1_CurrentCellChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //move to the next cell if we are in the first cell
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == 0 &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        //this does not throw an exception because 
        //the CurrentCell will be set some time later
        dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: You had me at "reentrancy"

Comment: upvote for "Reentrancy" too

Comment: Its definitely **Reentrancy**. Kevin, thanx for great answer!

Answer (score 12):

In electronic design, the problem is referred to as [contact bounce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce).

The correction for the problem when it happens with events is sometimes referred to as *de-bouncing*, named after bits of electronic circuitry that do the same thing.  So I suppose you could call the problem *event bounce*.

Comment: The question wasnt about electronic design

Comment: Nevertheless, the concept seems applicable to GUIs. After all, the term "bug" initially applied to hardware-related issues, but was transposed to software. You can criticize the author for not providing a definitive answer, but it's still an interesting remark, IMO.

Comment: The concept is _very_ applicable to GUIs and anything else that generates events.  In embedded systems, contact bounce is frequently corrected in software because it's easier and cheaper than adding a debounce circuit to each switch.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are touching two categories of bugs:

1. Assuming unity in the presence of multiplicity, and
2. race conditions.

I just came up with those names, I don't think they are standard.

Edit: I like the [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120228/is-there-a-name-for-more-events-than-expected-bug/120298#120298) by Kevin, which mentions reentrance. This is a standard term. Lack of reentrance is assuming a function can only happen once in any stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a general accepted term for it. However, i would have named it as

> - event flood  OR
> - trigger chain

Comment: I like *event flood*, though it makes me picture literally *hundreds* of excess events, not the 2 or 3 implied by the question.

Comment: +1, I've heard "event flood" on occasion before.  "Trigger chain" sounds like something else, though - like one event causes another, which causes another...